# How do I prove $n! > n^3 , \forall n ≥6, n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: induction

$P(n) : n! > n^3 , \forall n ≥6, n \in \mathbb{N}$

I'm not able to get the induction step done. Can anyone help me out with this? I'm stuck on this for the past 30 minutes.

It'd be helpful if you could also let me know your thought process.

Comment: Have you done the first step with $n=6$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Well, that doesn't really require any special skill, $6! =720 > 6^3 = 216$ I'm stuck on the hard part.

Comment: Ok you have to prove that form $$n!>n^3$$ follows $$(n+1)!>(n+1)^3$$

Comment: @William: that helps. Showing what you've done and where you're stuck is what people expect here.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes yes, I was able to prove $n! > n^2, n≥4$ easily. I'm not sure how to deal with them cubes though.

Comment: The induction step requires $n^3(n+1) > (n+1)^3$

Comment: Hint: For $n\ge6$, $$\left(\frac{n+1}n\right)^3\le\frac{343}{216}$$ and $$\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\ge7$$

Comment: I wonder if you could prove $n!\gt (n+1)^2$ for $n\ge 5$ rather than doing the induction steps others have suggested. This would build on the proof for $n^2$ you have already done.

Comment: This question shows *zero* "research effort". You have been stuck on it the past 30 minutes. OK. What have you tried in those 30 minutes? Detail your thoughts. Where exactly are you getting stuck in the induction step? And don't just say "them cubes"--that is helpful to precisely no one.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Oh alright, I would upload a pic of my work, but I'm not sure if you would be able to follow my write up so..

Comment: @William You're not new to this site--you shouldn't upload a picture. Type up your work using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) like everyone else. What you are doing is simply lazy--there's no indictment of your ability or intelligence but certainly one of your effort.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow my man, typing all those steps would take me another 30 minutes, that's why I tried to keep my question straight on point.

Comment: @William Why should others bother writing out answers that may take 30 minutes to write up then? Your question is *not* on point, and that's the issue--you have given no one clarity as to what exactly it is that is giving you a problem. And this is not new for you either. Previous such questions from you: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2857975/191378), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2796560/191378), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2849961/191378) (just to name a few). I will say no more, but your effort is highly questionable.

Comment: Thirty minutes is hardly a long time, @William; you need to improve your stamina!

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** This is not an inductive argument.  However, it is too long to be written as a comment.  Other answers have covered how to do the job inductively.

Suppose that $n\geq 6$ is an integer.  Let $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Define $$S:=\big\{(a,b,c)\big|\,a,b,c\in[n]\big\}=[n]^3$$
and
$$T:=\big\{\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right)\,\big|\,\left(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\right)\text{ is a permutation of }(1,2,\ldots,n)\big\}\,.$$
We shall construct an injective function $f:S\to T$ that is not surjective.  It follows immediately that
$$n^3=|S|=\big|\text{im}(f)\big|<|T|=n!\,.$$

Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be arbitrary elements of $[n]$.  If $a$, $b$, and $c$ are pairwise distinct elements of $[n]$, then let $\left\{x_4,x_5,\ldots,x_n\right\}=[n]\setminus\{a,b,c\}$, where $x_4<x_5<\ldots<x_n$.  We define $$f\big((a,b,c)\big):=\left(a,b,c,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8,\ldots,x_n\right)\,.$$
If $a=b$ and $b\neq c$, then let $\left\{x_3,x_4,\ldots,x_n\right\}=[n]\setminus\{a,b,c\}$, where $x_3<x_4<\ldots<x_n$.  We define
$$f\big((a,b,c)\big):=\left(a,c,x_3,x_5,x_4,x_6,x_7,x_8,\ldots,x_n\right)\,.$$
If $a\neq b$ and $b=c$, then let $\left\{x_3,x_4,\ldots,x_n\right\}=[n]\setminus\{a,b,c\}$, where $x_3<x_4<\ldots<x_n$.  We define
$$f\big((a,b,c)\big):=\left(a,b,x_3,x_4,x_6,x_5,x_7,x_8,\ldots,x_n\right)\,.$$
If $a=c$ and $a\neq b$, then let $\left\{x_3,x_4,\ldots,x_n\right\}=[n]\setminus\{a,b,c\}$, where $x_3<x_4<\ldots<x_n$.  We define
$$f\big((a,b,c)\big):=\left(a,b,x_3,x_6,x_5,x_4,x_7,x_8,\ldots,x_n\right)\,.$$
Finally, if $a=b=c$, then let $\left\{x_2,x_3,\ldots,x_n\right\}=[n]\setminus\{a,b,c\}$, where $x_2<x_3<\ldots<x_n$.  We define
$$f\big((a,b,c)\big):=\left(a,x_2,x_3,x_6,x_4,x_5,x_7,x_8,\ldots,x_n\right)\,.$$
It is clear that $f$ is injective.  Note that $f$ is not surjective because
$$(1,2,3,5,6,4,7,8,9,\ldots,n)\notin\text{im}(f)\,.$$

**P.S.** The reason that this proof fails for $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is that the definition of $f$ requires at least six coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiplying $$n!>n^3$$ by $n+1>0$ we get

$$n!(n+1)=(n+1)!>n^3(n+1)$$ it remaines to prove that $$n^3(n+1)>(n+1)^3$$ is hold.
The last inequality is equivalent to $$n^3-n^2-2n-1>0$$
Since $$n!=(n-1)!n$$ we can also write $$(n-1)!>n^2$$

Comment: I'm not sure, but that last inequality looks like a mess..I don't see what can you with do with it?

Comment: @William: you can write the last inequality as $n^3>(n+1)^2$. Can you prove this for $n>3$?

Answer (score 0):

The induction step starts with

$$(n+1)!=(n+1)(n!)>(n+1)(n^3)$$

So you have to show that $$(n+1)(n^3)\ge (n+1)^3$$ for $n\ge 6$

That is proving $$(n^3)\ge (n+1)^2$$ for $n\ge 6$

Can you take over from here?

Answer (score 0):

An option (no induction).

Let $n \ge 6$, $n$ integer.

We want to show

$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{n^3} (n-3)! > 1$;

$(1-1/n)(1-2/n)(n-3)! \ge$

$(1-1/6)(1-2/6)(n-3)! = (5/9)(n-3)! >$

$(1/2)(n-3)! >1$, since

$(n-3)! \ge 6$, for $n \ge 6$.